# Как использовать bottom navigation view в API 17-19?

Tags: java, android

Можно ли использовать например `bottom navigation view` в android 4.2 если она вроде как предназначено для android 6.0 и старше, и если можно то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Можно ли использовать например `bottom navigation view` в android 4.2

Да, можно. Этот компонент доступен в Design Support Library начиная с версии 25.0.0.

Для использования `BottomNavigationView` необходимо подключить зависимость:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
```

которая позволит использовать данный компонент на Android 2.1 и выше.

PS. Еще есть очень удобная библиотека [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar).